# Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, suse

when i used the the requets module to get a url's text,there is an Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.5.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3-1.21.1-py3.5.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 588, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3-1.21.1-py3.5.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 250, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3-1.21.1-py3.5.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 821, in _new_conn
    raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excuteUpdate.py", line 123, in <module>
    downloadList = getapkList(list)
  File "excuteUpdate.py", line 35, in getapkList
    text = requests.get(detail_path).text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.5.egg/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.5.egg/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.5.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.5.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.5.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

I have installed ssl-1.0.2,and used the command

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
make
make install
```

but it's not useful;

this is for get a url's text to parse.

the code just like this:

```
text = requests.get(detail_path).text
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908938/python-cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available)

Comment: Upgrading the version of python to 3.7.6 solved this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question:
first,I reinstall the openssl-1.0.2,and use

```
mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl.bak

mv /usr/include/bin/openssl /usr/include/bin/openssl.bak
```

to remove the old ssl's softlink,then

```
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/include/bin/openssl /usr/include/bin/openssl
```

finally,remake and install the python source code,build the softlink ,this question just be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this error (as detailed in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514668/cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available)) is that you have a file of your own named *ssl.py*, your script will import this file and cause this same error message to appear.